# North arrow not syncing with map QGIS 2.18

Tags: print-composer, north-arrow, rotate

I read about clicking on the 'sync with map' option after adding a north arrow (Layout -add image)(in Print composer), and I've done that, but when I rotate the map, the north arrow does not rotate with it. I've tried refreshing.
What have I missed?

edit _ this is still an issue.

edit - solved it.
There are TWO places where you have to tell it which map the N arrow should rotate with.
1 is in the layout tab for the image, under general settings, make sure reference map has the right map selected. THEN go to item properties, expand image rotation and select the sync with map option and tell it which map.

Comment: I couldn't replicate that error with a fresh composition including only a map and an arrow linked to it. Please check, whether you only have one map-element in your composition and if not, if your arrow is synced with the correct map. Otherwise you could try to start fresh as in building a new composition.

Comment: I just tried it again. new print composer, one map, one north arrow (add image), click on sync to map. That box is now checked. Rotate map, N arrow stays stubbornly motionless.

Comment: I also checked the map number.

Comment: Maybe a redundant question: Did you try a different arrow?

Comment: I tried a couple of different arrows.

Comment: Just tried another, but no difference. The map rotates, but the north arrow doesn't move. I even tried grouping the arrow stubbornly continues to point up.

Comment: Perhaps it might help to post screenshots of exactly steps you've taken showing what you've selected and tried, so we know for sure what settings you have used and what you mean by rotating the map (sounds tedious but I can't see how anyone will be able to help otherwise; I can't replicate the issue either - the bug I usually get is images occasionally rotated when the map isn't!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are TWO places where you have to tell it which map the N arrow should rotate with. 1 is in the layout tab for the image, under general settings, make sure reference map has the right map selected. THEN go to item properties, expand image rotation and select the sync with map option and tell it which map.